# Can be justified $\zeta(3)=\lim_{n\to\infty}-3\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{\nu=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{\nu+1}}{\nu+1}\binom{3k^3-1}{\nu}$?

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, power-series, binomial-theorem

My main goal is understand useful facts about my computations, that could be wrong, the way shold be too a street without exit looking for a evaluation of Apéry's constant, since I don't use any special method.

In a hand we have that
$$\int_0^1\sum_{k=1}^n z^{3k^3-1}dz=\sum_{k=1}^n\int_0^1 z^{3k^3-1}dz=\frac{1}{3}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k^3},$$
since the sum is finite, leaving the partial sum of $\frac{1}{3}\zeta(3)$, where $\zeta(3)$ is **Apéry's constant**, by elementary integration since previous partial sum starts as 
$$\sum_{k=1}^n z^{3k^3-1}=z^2+z^{23}+z^{80}+z^{191}+z^{374}+\cdots$$

**Wolfram Alpha** doesn't give me the convergence of corresponding infinite series, neither a closed form for the sum of partial $\sum_{k=1}^n z^{3k^3-1}$. *I believe that the convergence holds for infinite series in $|z|<1$.*

In the other hand we take the **Taylor expansion series** around $z=1$ for the monomial $z^{3k^3-1}$ (fixed an integer $k\geq 1$), this

$$z^{3k^3-1}=\sum_{\nu=0}^\infty\binom{3k^3-1}{\nu}(z-1)^{\nu},$$
then if it is possible (*I don't know if I have convergence in the following computations, well I've computed with a monomial, and change $\sum^\infty$ with $\int^{z=1}$, where $|z|=1$*)
$$\int_0^1\sum_{k=1}^n z^{3k^3-1}dz=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{\nu=0}^\infty\binom{3k^3-1}{\nu}\Big(\frac{(z-1)^{\nu+1}}{\nu +1}\Big|_0^1=-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{\nu=0}^\infty\binom{3k^3-1}{\nu}\frac{(-1)^{\nu+1}}{\nu +1}.$$

*Thus*

$$\frac{1}{3}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k^3}=-\sum_{\nu=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{\nu+1}}{(\nu +1)!}\sum_{k=1}^{n}(3k^3-1)(3k^3-2)\cdots(3k^3-1-\nu+1).$$

> **Question.** a)Can I take the Taylor series for the monomial $z^{3k^3-1}$ around $z=1$ and after change  $\sum^\infty$ and $\int^{z=1}$ as my computations does show? b) If there are no mistakes, if feasible give a sum for $\sum_{k=1}^n (3k^3-1)(3k^3-2)\cdots(3k^3-\nu)$? (Since I know that the sum $\zeta(3)$ is very difficult, I look for an alternative identity that I've computed, but my main goal is to know if my computations were justified).

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Since we are dealing with integers, you could have simply written $\sum\limits_{\nu=0}^{3k^3}.$ And yes, your expression checks out numerically.

Comment: Very thanks much @Lucian, now I understand, you say that Taylor expansion series has only a number of finite terms. Too, I grateful to you since you check out numerically. I will wait what say other users, in the way to obtain an answer of the post but very thanks much another time.

Comment: What do you mean by 'the sum $\zeta(3)$ is very difficult'$?  If you mean that the original formula doesn't converge quickly, this is true but there are a broad number of fast-convergent series; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ap%C3%A9ry's_constant#Fast_convergence for more details. If you're hoping to get a better understanding of properties of the number (e.g., degree of irrationality or the like) then series probably aren't the best direction to look...

Comment: Thanks @StevenStadnicki I am an amateur,  truly this details are out my hands,  I do this to take my time. My main goal is obtain an answer with mathematics that I can understand to refresh and encourage to me, to study more mathematics.  I understand your critics.

Comment: I wish you Math Christmas and a Happy New $\frac{\left(\zeta(2)^2-\zeta(0)\zeta(4)\right)^3}{\zeta(0)^6\zeta(4)\zeta(8)}.$ After the bounty question was answered I will delete this last comment. Thanks